# Swift Percent Item Moved Across Screen

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

**Problem:**

You are trying to get a number from 0 to 1 depending on how much a view within a scroll view has moved across the visible screen.

**Criteria**:

- The value should return 0 when the view is on the left side OR off screen to the left.
- The value should return 1 when the view is on the right side OR off screen to the right.

**Attempt:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard let firstScrollviewView = items.first else {return}
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    // This should return a value between 0 and 1
    let xOffset = firstScrollviewView.convert(CGPoint(x: firstScrollviewView.frame.minX, y: 0), to: view).x
    var percentViewMovedOnVisibleScreen: CGFloat = xOffset / screenWidth

    let minValue: CGFloat = 0
    let maxValue: CGFloat = 1
    percentViewMovedOnVisibleScreen = max(min(percentViewMovedOnVisibleScreen, maxValue), minValue)

    // RETURN value between 0 and 1 - NOT CORRECT
    print("HERE x: ", percentViewMovedOnVisibleScreen)
}
```

This is really close, but I think the xOffset property is incorrect.

**GitHub:** https://github.com/Alexander-Frost/ViewContentOffset

Comment: First, you'll be much better off using constraints, rather than calculating frames. Second, your question is confusing... looking at your GitHub project, you add 4 subviews to your scroll view, but you're only checking the frame of the first one - which can be scrolled out-of-view to the left, but not to the right... you can only drag it a short way to the right. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @DonMag, yes. All I'm trying to do is get the percent a view has moved across the page. Adding the extra views in the project was just so you can scrolling space. The point conversion is incorrect here though

Comment: The percentViewMovedOnVisibleScreen variable is currently providing the % the view moved within the SCROLLVIEW but I want to get the percent moved in relation to the main VIEW.

Comment: OK - well, your code is essentially working, but you're evaluating the **left edge** of the first subview. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xOffset needed to change to:

```
let xOffset = scrollView.convert(CGPoint(x:firstScrollviewView.frame.minX, y: 0), to: view).x
```